# Авто-инкремент в emacs

Tags: emacs

К примеру есть строка:

```
print('value of 1 variable: ' + var1)
```

И надо, последовательно *скопипастить* таких строк **N** раз чтобы получилось:

```
print('value of 1 variable: ' + var1)
...
print('value of N variable: ' + varN)
```

Есть ли *нативный* способ в `emacs`, для того, чтобы не менять *вручную* цифры в строках и именах переменных? Если да, то можно делать те же вещи, только вместо примитивного *авто-инкремента* использовать *функцию* или *список переменных*?

Answer (score 0):

Это легко реализуется при помощи [макросов](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros).

Перейдите в начало строки:

```
print('value of variable: ' + var)
^
```

И выполните: `C-k <F3> C-y C-b C-x C-k <TAB> C-e C-m <F4> C-u 5 C-x e`, чтобы сгенерировать 5 строк с автоинкрементом:

```
print('value of variable: ' + var0)
print('value of variable: ' + var1)
print('value of variable: ' + var2)
print('value of variable: ' + var3)
print('value of variable: ' + var4)
```

В документации также [описано](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacrosTricks) как включить elisp код в макросы для реализации более сложной логики.